# Create a count of date values in R by group

Tags: r, date, count, aggregate

I have the tables below:

**1st Table:**

| ID | Expired | New | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | NA | 2021-02-01 | 1001 |
| 002 | NA | 2021-02-01 | 1001 |
| 003 | NA | 2021-02-21 | 1001 |
| 004 | NA | 2021-04-21 | 1001 |
| 005 | NA | 2021-04-21 | 1001 |
| 006 | NA | 2021-04-21 | 1001 |
| 006 | 2022-06-20 | 2021-04-21 | 1002 |
| 002 | 2021-08-10 | 2021-04-21 | 1002 |
| 003 | 2022-06-20 | 2021-05-01 | 1002 |
| 003 | 2022-06-20 | 2021-05-01 | 1002 |
| 003 | 2021-08-10 | 2021-05-21 | 1002 |
| 003 | 2021-08-10 | 2021-07-21 | 1002 |

**Desired Output:**

| Date | Group | New |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-01 | 1001 | 1 |
| 2021-02-01 | 1001 | 1 |
| 2021-02-02 | 1001 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 2022-06-20 | 1001 | 0 |
| 2022-06-20 | 1001 | 0 |
| 2021-02-01 | 1002 | 0 |
| 2021-02-01 | 1002 | 0 |
| 2021-02-02 | 1002 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 2022-06-19 | 1002 | 0 |
| 2022-06-20 | 1002 | 0 |

In the new table, I would like "date" to start from the earliest date (ex. 2021-02-01) in the table and end at the most recent date available (ex. 2022-06-20) and go date by date between those dates. It should do this for every group. If there is a way to do to this using the min and max function, that would be great since the dates in the datasets are changing from month to month.

Also, if, in the original table, there is no date for a group then in the new table the value of new for that date should be 0. If there is a date value in the original table for a group, that should be marked as 1 in the new table.

This is what I started with:

`sums <- data.frame(aggregate(completeddf["New"], by = completeddf[c("date", "Tier2_ID")], sum))`

But this only gives me the sum of 1's and 0's for each date value for each group. It doesn't go day by day. Replacing sum with count isn't working and gives the following error: `Error in UseMethod("count") :no applicable method for 'count' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"`

Thank you!

Comment: Hi John, would you mind double-checking your desired result? Your explanation and example do not match up; it would be helpful for answering the question if you would provide further detail.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood your situation, but here is a solution with the data I extracted from the table of your question

```r
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)
# Data
df <- data.frame(
  ID      = c("001","002","003","004","005","006","006","002","003","003","003","003"),
  Expired = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,"2022-06-20","2021-08-10","2022-06-20","2022-06-20","2021-08-10","2021-08-10"),
  New     = c("2021-02-01","2021-02-01", "2021-02-21","2021-04-21","2021-04-21","2021-04-21", "2021-04-21","2021-04-21","2021-05-01","2021-05-01", "2021-05-21","2021-07-21"),
  Group   = c(1001L,1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L)
)
# Sequence of all dates from 2021-02-01 to 2022-06-20
Date <- seq(min(as.Date(df$New)), max(as.Date(df$New)), by = "day")
df_date <- crossing(Date, Group = df$Group) # All different combinations of "Date" and "Group"

# Desired output
df %>%
  rename(Date = New) %>% 
  mutate(Date= as.Date(Date)) %>%  # Convert the "Date" column to a Date format
  select(- Group) %>% 
  right_join(df_date, by = "Date") %>% 
  arrange(Group, Date) %>%         # Sort dataframe by "Group" and "Date"
  mutate(New =  ifelse(is.na(ID), 0, 1)) %>% 
  select(Date, Group, New) %>% as.data.frame()

          Date Group New
1   2021-02-01  1001   1
2   2021-02-01  1001   1
3   2021-02-02  1001   0
4   2021-02-03  1001   0
5   2021-02-04  1001   0
...
1020 2022-06-18  1002   0
1021 2022-06-19  1002   0
1022 2022-06-20  1002   0
```

Comment: Hi, This is great. Essentially the date for each Group should start at 2021-02-01 and go until 2022-06-20. 

For example, group 1001 should have every day in between 2021-02-01 and 2022-06-20 and so should group 1002

Comment: @JohnTayson I think that's the case in the code above

Comment: @JohnTayson Does the `completeddf` dataframe already have all the days between 2021-02-01 and 2022-06-20 ?

Comment: no the completeddf dataframe does not have all the days in between 2021-02-01 and 2022-06-20. I think that your code will help create that in the new database.

Comment: @JohnTayson Please like my answer if it solves your problem partially and mark it as the accepted answer if it solves your problem completely

Comment: when sequencing between two, is there a way to find the find the min data in the set and the max date in the dataset and then sequence between the two? As the dataset is constantly being updated, writing each date manually is not the most efficient.

Comment: @JohnTayson Yes, `max(as.Date(df$New))` and `min(as.Date(df$New))`, provided that `New` is the Date variable. I will edit the answer